MongoDB with Spring boot application to fetch Embedded json
Hello I am learning to implement MongoDB features with spring boot application.
Question is fairly simple how do I make MongoTemplate.findOne fetch complete object.
My User entity class is below.
@Document(collection = "users")
@Data
@ToString
public class User {

  @MongoId(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
  private String id;

  @Size(max = 20)
  @NotBlank
  private String username;

  @NotBlank
  @Size(max = 50)
  @Email
  private String email;
  
  @NotBlank
  private String passwordHash;
  
  private Set<Role> roles = new HashSet<>();
  
  private Profile profile;
  private Date createdAt;
  private Date updatedAt;
  public User() {
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }
  public User(String username, String email, String passwordHash, String firstName, String lastName, String bio, String profilePicture) {
    this.profile = new Profile(firstName, lastName, bio, profilePicture);
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }

  public User(String username, String email, String passwordHash) {
    this.username = username;
    this.email = email;
    this.passwordHash = passwordHash;
    this.createdAt = new Date();
    this.updatedAt = new Date();
  }

  public User(String username, String email, String passwordHash, Profile profile) {
    this(username, email, passwordHash);
    this.profile = profile;
  }

  @Data
  @ToString
  @AllArgsConstructor
  @NoArgsConstructor
  public static class Profile {
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String firstName;
    
    @Size(max = 50)
    @NotBlank
    private String lastName;
    
    @Size(max = 300)
    private String bio;
    private String profilePicture;
  }
}

Roles.java
@Document(collection = "roles")
@Data
@NoArgsConstructor
@ToString
public class Role {
    
    @MongoId(targetType = FieldType.OBJECT_ID)
    private String id;

    private String description;
    
    private String roleName;
    
    private List<String> permissions;

    @CreatedDate
    private Date createAt;

    @LastModifiedDate
    private Date updateAt;
}

UserDao.findByUsername()
public Optional<User> findByUsername(String username) {
        Query query = new Query();
        query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("username").is(username));
        query.fields()
                .include("username")
                .include("email")
                .include("createdAt")
                .include("roles")
                .include("passwordHash")
                .include("profile");
        Optional<User> user = Optional.ofNullable(mongoTemplate.findOne(query, User.class));
        return user;
    }

When I am running this method, it is not fetching profile object, it is null always. Same goes for roles object.
Appreciate any help. Been wrapping my head around this, tried GenAI as well but not much luck.
If there is any other code snippet required please let me know.

For usage of mongoDB you can use like this : String id annoted with like @Id. Mongo automatic consider it as a objectId. This will work for MongoDB

Can you try like this :
query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("username").is(username));
                                |

query.addCriteria(Criteria.where("username").regex(username, "i");
i represent ignore case of letter.

If this is not working then provide your proper code like repo., etc
